# deciphering growing lights specifics

Tags: indoors, tomatoes, peppers, grow-lamp

What spectrum and strength of light are best suited for indoor tomato and pepper growing? I have around 2,5m2 of surface. The room walls will be coated with mylar.

If you can be product specific, that would be great, since I find commercial descriptions rather confusing. For example: [light product here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XC3LBI2). This light is 300W, but lower in the description is stated that it consumes only 132watt±10%.

Apparently it generates 2.5 more energy than it consumes :))

Other manufactures describe lamps in a similar way.

Thanks for help.

Comment: 600 watts, high pressure sodium with a ballast. This ballast one ballast is compatible with high pressure sodium 600 watt bulb (which is what I use) the same digital ballast is compatible with metal halide conversion bulb from 400 watts to 1000 watts.  High Tech HTG Supply on the internet.  Glad you are doing this!  Makes life so very much easier!!

Comment: The European Union requires electrical bulbs to be energy-efficient, that's why they generate more than the consumption. Sellers of old style less efficient bulbs have to pay important fees, so they prefer to sell the new stuff.

Comment: hehe I doubt that european union forced light bulbs to generate more energy than they consume. But tight restriction do apply here. for example  you can't buy a strong vacuum cleaner. That way you spend less energy per time of vacuuming, but you get to work 2 as long, because vacuum cleaner just wont vacuum efficiently.  Anyway, about the lamp above. I think the manufacturer just put 300W in the name of the light for advertising purposes.

Comment: I am not a technical person, so it is possible that my explanation is incorrect from physics point of view. What I want to say is that now there are light bulbs that consume less than the old bulbs for the same light. The most common example is a light bulb of 21W that is equivalent to an old bulb of 100W. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-out_of_incandescent_light_bulbs#European_Union

Answer (score 2):

The important factors are the light spectrum and the lumens , not the watts. I have found more information for aquarium light products than garden lights . A metal halide ( not halogen ) with a 5000 C temperature rating would be good but use a lot of power ; available in wattage from 150 to 500 and maybe more.